# qsort for structures

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student
{
char nume[20];
int grupa,nr_credite;
} S;

int cmpg(const void *a, const void *b);
int cmpc(const void *a, const void *b);
void ex();

int main()
{
ex();                  //main program
return(0);
}

void ex()               //sorting function
{
   int n,i,c;
   S st[100];

scanf("%d", &n);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%s %d %d", st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);
size_t no = sizeof(S)/sizeof(st->grupa);

size_t noo = sizeof(S)/sizeof(st->nr_credite);

qsort(st->grupa, no, sizeof(S), cmpg);
qsort(st->grupa, noo, sizeof(S), cmpc);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%s %d %d", st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);

}

int cmpg(const void *a, const void *b)          
{
struct Student *ia = (struct Student *)a;
struct Student *ib = (struct Student *)b;
return (int)(ia->grupa - ib->grupa);
}

int cmpc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
struct Student *ia = (struct Student *)a;
struct Student *ib = (struct Student *)b;
return (int)(ib->nr_credite - ia->nr_credite);
}
```

So the thing is I have some students in some different groups and they have a different number of credits. I want to use qsort to order them by group (ascending) and inside of each group to sort them by the number of credits(descending).

I have this code but it is stopping with this exit code: Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s)).

Comment: What kind of relation this question has with css?

Comment: @oprea rebeca  What does this size_t no = sizeof(S)/sizeof(st->grupa); mean?

Comment: What do you think, would be the values for `no` and `noo` and what should that represent? Hint: You want to sort array `st`, not a single element `st->grupa` that is addressed in a weird way...

Comment: @MohammadUsman The both contain the letter 'c'.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow tha no is the abbreviation from number. this is what I used for the size needed in qsort....

Comment: Enable warnings. I get these warnings: `warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 2 has type 'int *'` and `warning C4022: 'qsort': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
void ex()
{
  int n, i;
  S st[100];

  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%s %d %d", st[i].nume, &st[i].grupa, &st[i].nr_credite);

  qsort(st, n, sizeof(S), cmpg);
  //    ^   ^   ^
  //    |   |   |
  //    |   |   size of one element
  //    |   |-- number of elements in array
  //    |-- address of first element of the array
  //

  qsort(st, n, sizeof(S), cmpc);

  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%s %d %d\n", st[i].nume, st[i].grupa, st[i].nr_credite);  // removed &s
}
```

Comment: it's printing some long numbers...other than that it's working

Comment: where did the no disappeared?

Comment: @oprearebeca it works fine here. Did you remove the `&`s in the `printf`?

Comment: Yes. I have not seen them, cause I copy paste from the scanf...I was lazy I forgot to delete the & and i was also blocking at qsort ... I did not get to printf...thank you

Comment: "works fine here" does it?  *order them by group (ascending) and inside of each group to sort them by the number of credits(descending)* is not likely to be accomplished by sorting by group and *then* sorting by credits. What is your test case?

Comment: @n.m. yes, it does not sort correctly. But that was not really the question here. Rather I should have written "the usage of qsort is now correct"

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your calls of qsort. What `qsort` expects is the array to sort, the number of elements that should be sorted, the size of each element and the comparison function. So what you need is:

```
qsort(st, n, sizeof(S), cmpg);
qsort(st, n, sizeof(S), cmpc);
```

And your printf is also wrong:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%s %d %d", st[i].nume, st[i].grupa, st[i].nr_credite);
```

BTW, you never test for errors which is bad:

- if n>100, you will get an out of bond access on S
- if there is an incorrect value in one the the answers, you will have read errors but still proceed with indeterminate values.

---

As noted in comments, this only fixes the error. But as `qsort` is not required to be a stable sort, two consecutive sorts may not produce what you want.

Comment: @oprearebeca "it's working fine" No it isn't. *order them by group (ascending) and inside of each group to sort them by the number of credits(descending).* Two calls to qsort don't do that.

Comment: @n.m. yeah it doesn't work if you have different groups

Comment: @oprearebeca hint: for the sorting to work you need to call `qsort` only once and change the comparision logic in the compare function.